# Least amount of coins to use given an amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function in javascript/jquery to work out what the minimum number of coins it would take to add up to a total inputed amount.

So I have an object array of the coins:

```
var coins = [
    {
        pennies: 200, 
        print: '£2'
    }, 
    {
        pennies: 100, 
        print: '£1'
    }, 
    {
        pennies: 50, 
        print: '50p'
    }, 
    {
        pennies: 20, 
        print: '20p'}, 
    {
        pennies: 10,
        print: '10p'
    }, 
    {
        pennies: 5, 
        print: '5p'}, 
    {
        pennies: 2, 
        print: '2p'
    },
    {
        pennies: 1, 
        print: '1p'
    }
];
var $input = $('input');
$input.keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

And an input field in my HTML.

So if someone enters 123p I would like the form to return 1 x £1, 1 x 20p, 1 x 2p and 1 x 1p.

I'm struggling to figure out where to start. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's more of a math or algorithm problem than a js related. Start with highest rank coin that can fit into your number. Subtract  the biggest number of times it can fit into your input number. Then with remaining amount do the same operation - find biggest coin it that can fit and subract the biggest amount of times, and again and again up until you get zero.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to iterate over the `coins` array, starting from the highest denomination:

```js
const coins=[{pennies:200,print:'£2'},{pennies:100,print:'£1'},{pennies:50,print:'50p'},{pennies:20,print:'20p'},{pennies:10,print:'10p'},{pennies:5,print:'5p'},{pennies:2,print:'2p'},{pennies:1,print:'1p'}];

const getCoins = penniesToGo => coins.reduce((coinCountStr, { pennies, print }) => {
  const numCoins = Math.floor(penniesToGo / pennies);
  if (numCoins < 1) return coinCountStr;
  penniesToGo -= numCoins * pennies;
  const thisCoinStr = `${numCoins}x ${print}`;
  return coinCountStr ? coinCountStr + ', ' + thisCoinStr : thisCoinStr;
}, '');

console.log(getCoins(201));
console.log(getCoins(333));
console.log(getCoins(6));
```